# Acumatica Customer Location AllowEdit

Tags: acumatica

I have a user field that stores a business account and location in both the QuoteMaint.CopyQuoteFilter and OpportunityMaint.CopyQuoteFilter. On the screen layout I put AllowEdit = true. When the user clicks on the pencil, it opens the Vendor Locations, even though they are working in sales. Is there a way for me to force it to open the Customer Locations instead?

Here is the DAC for the Location Id I am trying to drill to.

```
[LocationID(typeof(Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<usrBAccountId>>>),
        DisplayName = "Location",
        DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr),
        BqlField = typeof(usrLocationID))] // typeof(Location.locationID))]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<CROpportunity.locationID, Where<CROpportunity.opportunityID, Equal<Current<CRQuote.opportunityID>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual int? UsrLocationID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrLocationID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrLocationID> { }
```

Thanks!

Comment: PO and SO pages redirect to the corresponding Vendor/Customer location pages. It should be feasible in your scenario as well. Please share the DAC extension definition for the new fields

Comment: Thank you for the response Fernando, I have updated my post to include the DAC for the user fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do it manually with a PXAction. Add a PXButton (optionally style it with the Edit image) or a link control then add an event handler in which you create the target graph and redirect to it.

Here's an example of a event handler that redirects to one of the many graph handling Location DAC:

```
    public PXDBAction<BAccount> addLocation;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.AddNewLocation)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntry)]
    public virtual void AddLocation()
    {
        var row = BAccount.Current;
        if (row == null || row.BAccountID == null) return;

        LocationMaint graph = null;
        switch (row.Type)
        {
            case BAccountType.VendorType:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AP.VendorLocationMaint>();
                break;
            case BAccountType.CustomerType:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AR.CustomerLocationMaint>();
                break;
            default:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<LocationMaint>();
                break;
        }


        var newLocation = (Location)graph.Location.Cache.CreateInstance();
        newLocation.BAccountID = row.BAccountID;
        var locType = LocTypeList.CustomerLoc;
        switch (row.Type)
        {
            case BAccountType.VendorType:
                locType = LocTypeList.VendorLoc;
                break;
            case BAccountType.CombinedType:
                locType = LocTypeList.CombinedLoc;
                break;
        }
        newLocation.LocType = locType;
        graph.Location.Insert(newLocation);
        PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);

    }
```

The issue occurs because Location DAC has many PXPrimaryGraph and at runtime it doesn't know which one to use in your context so it fallbacks on the first from the list.

```
[PXCacheName("Location")]
[PXPrimaryGraph(new[] { typeof(VendorLocationMaint), 
                        typeof(CustomerLocationMaint), 
                        typeof(BranchMaint), 
                        typeof(EmployeeMaint), 
                        typeof(LocationMaint) }, 
                new[] { typeof(Select<Location, Where<bAccountID, Equal<Current<bAccountID>>, And<locationID, Equal<Current<locationID>>, And<Where<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.vendorLoc>, Or<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.combinedLoc>>>>>>>), 
                        typeof(Select<Location, Where<bAccountID, Equal<Current<bAccountID>>, And<locationID, Equal<Current<locationID>>, And<Where<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.customerLoc>, Or<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.combinedLoc>>>>>>>), 
                        typeof(Select2<Branch, InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Branch.bAccountID>>, InnerJoin<Location, On<bAccountID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>, And<locationID, Equal<BAccount.defLocationID>>>>>, Where<bAccountID, Equal<Current<bAccountID>>, And<locationID, Equal<Current<locationID>>, And<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.companyLoc>>>>>), 
                        typeof(Select2<EPEmployee, InnerJoin<Location, On<bAccountID, Equal<EPEmployee.bAccountID>, And<locationID, Equal<EPEmployee.defLocationID>>>>, Where<bAccountID, Equal<Current<bAccountID>>, And<locationID, Equal<Current<locationID>>, And<Current<locType>, Equal<LocTypeList.employeeLoc>>>>>), 
                        typeof(Select<Location, Where<bAccountID, Equal<Current<bAccountID>>, And<locationID, Equal<Current<locationID>>>>>) })]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<Location, LeftJoin<LocationAPAccountSub, On<LocationAPAccountSub.bAccountID, Equal<bAccountID>, And<LocationAPAccountSub.locationID, Equal<vAPAccountLocationID>>>, LeftJoin<LocationARAccountSub, On<LocationARAccountSub.bAccountID, Equal<bAccountID>, And<LocationARAccountSub.locationID, Equal<cARAccountLocationID>>>, LeftJoin<LocationAPPaymentInfo, On<LocationAPPaymentInfo.bAccountID, Equal<bAccountID>, And<LocationAPPaymentInfo.locationID, Equal<vPaymentInfoLocationID>>>, LeftJoin<BAccountR, On<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<bAccountID>>>>>>>), Persistent = true)]
public class Location : IBqlTable, IPaymentTypeDetailMaster, ILocation
{
}
```

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. I haven't tried this yet, but I think I may try setting it to a type of CustomerLocation to see if that works out. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I successfully tested manual redirection. Not sure setting the current context is going to work but it's worth a try: Base.Caches[typeof(Location)].Current.LocType = LocTypeList.CustomerLoc *or* Base.Caches[typeof(Location)].Current.LocType = LocTypeList.CombinedLoc

Comment: I had to modify it a bit to work with my needs, but this works - thanks for the assistance!